# ReactJS and MongoDB Accessing Object Property Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, mongodb, object

`console.log(res.data.data.wallet.transactions);`

How can I get transactions[] > 0{} > balance property's Value
[image]

`console.log(res.data.data.wallet.transactions["0"].balance);` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution :

```
 console.log(res.data.data.wallet.transactions[0][0].balance);
```